# iOS: Disallow "Open in..." menu and immediately open attached email file in specific application

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, swift3

I would like to ask you, if there is possible to open email attachment file immediately in my own application, not to pop up "Open in...".

Now I have created "Document types" for example .xxx and always when some email has an attachment with extension .xxx then the attachment has small icon of my application, but when I click on it, then pop up "Open in..." menu and I must select again my application to open in... This is working like a charm but...

Is there some way to open it with just one click immediately and not show "Open in..." menu? The menu  should be visible only if I stay clicked for some time on icon...

I have been searching for a while, but without any answers, thanks for feedback! Currently doing this on Xamarin for iOS, but I guess same it will be for a swift...

Answer (score 0):

**Not Possible**  in iOS. You can't force user to open  supported document with your app only.

Comment: Realy not possible? Just asking, because attachment as .txt, .docx or .pdf always open in some editor (internal) and never asking to open in another app despite stay on icon for some time...

Comment: It only happens when you don't have another app wich supports these doc. Try installing app which support PDF or Docx  -- It will  display OpenIn Poup .

Comment: Ok, understand, just theoretically any possibility to disallow share it by mail, cloud, message, messenger and so on? Because this app is still there and not support any .xxx extensions...